# How to get object's unique id within a recyclerView on Firebase Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using a recyclerView to display some objects of the Firebase Database. These objects are not users. What i need is to get the key of the object when clicked. Something like holder.getKey(). I am using FirebaseRecyclerOptions and FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, so i do not have a list of the objects. Just a reference. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following inside `onBindViewHolder`:

```
 String keyId = this.getRef(position).getKey();
```

`getRef(position)` will return the source location of your reference and `getKey()` will retrieve the node.

You can check the code in the github repo:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java#L113

Comment: I cannot do this inside the onClickListener. I need to get the key of the object that i click

Comment: You can add onclicklistener inside inbindviewholder

Comment: The solution inside onClickListener was String keyId = getRef(position).getKey(). Thank you